# Migrate from Interbase to MySQL

Tags: mysql, migration, interbase

I need to migrate a big database from Interbase to MySQL, I'd like to have suggestions about free and non-free tools to perform this task.

I've found this one: http://dbconvert.com/convert-firebird-to-mysql-pro.php

But I'd like to have advises by someone that has done this kind of task to have concrete advises.